# conversion from std::map<std::basic_string<char>,std::pair<int,int(*)(const std::vector::Mat

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

I have defined new type:

```
typedef int(* func) (const std::vector<cv::Mat>&, cv::Mat&);
```

Then I did class member:

```
std::map< std::string, std::pair<int,func> > functions;
```

In function, in first line:

```
pair<funcId,func> functionSet::getRandomFunction() const
{
    map<string, pair<int,func>>::iterator it = functions.begin();
    std::advance(it, functions.size());

    string name = it->first;
    func function = it->second.second;
    int argumentsNumber = it->second.first;
    funcId id = make_pair(argumentsNumber,name);

    pair<funcId,func> p = make_pair(id,function);

    return p;
}
```

I got this error:

> error: conversion from 'std::map,
>   std::pair&, cv::Mat&)> >
>   ::const_iterator {aka std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator, std::pair&, cv::Mat&)> > >}' to non-scalar type
>   'std::map, std::pair&, cv::Mat&)> >::iterator {aka
>   std::_Rb_tree_iterator,
>   std::pair&, cv::Mat&)> > >}'
>   requested
>            map>::iterator it = functions.begin();

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your method marked as const, and so `this` has type `const functionSet*`. Change you first line:

```
map<string, pair<int,func>>::const_iterator it = functions.begin();
```

or if your compiler supports C++11 standard:

```
auto it = functions.cbegin();
```

Comment: Thanks this was a life saver.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the output again:

```
conversion from
'std::map, std::pair&, cv::Mat&)> >::const_iterator {...}'
to non-scalar type
'std::map, std::pair&, cv::Mat&)> >::iterator {...}'
```

So it seems that `functions` is a const map, its `begin()` returns a const iterator, and it cannot be converted into a normal iterator.

The reason it is constant because because `getRandomFunction` is a constant member function and therefore it can see the class members as constants.

As you do not modify the map, simply using `const_iterator` should solve the problem:

```
map<string, pair<int,func>>::const_iterator it = functions.begin();
```